# JQuery, how to find conditional list of div's with similar ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a structure of html like this:

```
<input id="trigger0" type="hidden" value="Zero" />
<input id="trigerId0" type="hidden" value="8" />
<input id="trigger1" type="hidden" value="One" />
<input id="trigerId1" type="hidden" value="-1" />
<input id="trigger2" type="hidden" value="Two" />
<input id="trigerId2" type="hidden" value="6" />
<input id="trigger3" type="hidden" value="Three" />
<input id="trigerId3" type="hidden" value="4" />Testing:
<div >value</div>
<input type="text" name="fname" id='finalValue' size='200'>
```

I know that $("[id^='trigger']") will get all four trigger inputs.  Is it possible to create a jQuery statement that will only return the trigger where the corresponding trigerId is NOT -1, in the code above, that would be trigger1, trigger3, and trigger4

### Thanks in advance

Sorry folks, I cut/paste the wrong id, need to look at the trigerId values to determine if a trigger should be returned.  In the real situation, the names are NOT the same, so I removed a g from trigerId to make sure $("[id^='trigger']") didn't get the trigerId.

Comment: Can you clarify, do you want the results like in my answer or the triggers themself like Andreas suggested?

Answer (score 2):

Use [**:not()**](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) while applying the condition to the `value` attribute itself

```
$('[id^="triggerId"]:not([value="-1"])')
```

```js
console.log($('[id^="triggerId"]:not([value="-1"])') );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="trigger0" type="hidden" value="???"/>
<input id="triggerId0" type="hidden" value="8"/>
<input id="trigger1" type="hidden" value="???"/>
<input id="triggerId1" type="hidden" value="-1"/>
<input id="trigger2" type="hidden" value="???"/>
<input id="triggerId2" type="hidden" value="6"/>
<input id="trigger3" type="hidden" value="???"/>
<input id="triggerId3" type="hidden" value="4"/>
```

Comment: How does this fulfill the requirement? "that will **only return the trigger** where the **corresponding triggerId is NOT -1**" Your selector returns every input but `triggerId1`

Comment: @Andreas, `that will only return the trigger where the corresponding triggerId is NOT -1`

Comment: @Andreas, right, he want every input that does not have a value of -1

Comment: Now you get every `triggerId` but not the `trigger`

Comment: @Andreas, `that would be triggerId1, triggerId3, and triggerId4`

Comment: @Andreas, thats what is logged in the console

Comment: Sam asks for the `trigger`s and not the `triggerId`s

Comment: @Andreas, I see your point, I left a comment right under the question. Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** to filter from jQuery object

```js
$('[id^="triggerId"]').filter(function() {
  return this.value != '-1';
}).each(function() {
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="trigger0" type="hidden" value="???" />
<input id="triggerId0" type="hidden" value="8" />
<input id="trigger1" type="hidden" value="???" />
<input id="triggerId1" type="hidden" value="-1" />
<input id="trigger2" type="hidden" value="???" />
<input id="triggerId2" type="hidden" value="6" />
<input id="trigger3" type="hidden" value="???" />
<input id="triggerId3" type="hidden" value="4" />
```

Comment: "that will **only return the trigger** where the **corresponding triggerId** is NOT -1"

Comment: @Andreas, `that will only return the trigger where the corresponding triggerId is NOT -1`

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the attribute selector like this:

```
$('[id ^= "triggerId"][value != "-1"]')
```

EDIT:

Oh! You want the `id='trigger#` for the matched `id='triggerId#`. Do this:

```
var triggers = [];
jQuery('[id^="triggerId"][value!="-1"]').each(function() {
  var id = jQuery(this).attr('id').replace(/[^0-9]+/, '');
  triggers.push( jQuery('#trigger'+id) );
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what I was looking for:

```
var finalValue = document.getElementById('finalValue'); 
$('[id^="trigger"]').
filter(function (index) {
    return $("#trigerId" + index).val() > -1;
}).
each(function (e, i) {
    finalValue.value = finalValue.value + " " + e + ":" + this.value
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.  **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)